# Export Parsed Data To CSV Format From Visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, attachment, json, excel, salesforceexcelconnector

*I re-titled this so as to make it simpler in concept - JSON is not directly the issue, it's the ability to export data that appears in a VF page.*

We have a situation where, when Leads (or Accounts) are Merged, we end up with a JSON text file attachment from the now-deleted record with key fields stored in it.  We have a VisualForce page that is embedded in the Lead/Account layout which parses and shows the attachments as if they were typical objects.

**Sample of JSON data in attachments**

```
"AE_Keeper__c":false, 
"OwnerId":"00560000000mIAOAA2", 
"Country_List__c":"United States of America", 
"PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail":false,
```

**Sample of VisualForce**

[image]

The question becomes...

**Does anyone know of a simple way to export what the VisualForce page has already parsed into a CSV file?**  Perhaps a button on the VF for "export to CSV"?   My feeling is, since VF has already processed it.

My alternatives so far are very hack-ish.

- Export the JSON attachments and push them into Excel and have Excel parse them (there will be 1 to infinite, probably no more than 5-10 usually, files)
- Click each record in the VF interface which shows it in typical two-column SF page layout mode - highlight and paste each one into Excel and have Excel parse it out (variation on the above theme)
- Click a button in VF which displays those records in plain text, delimited, ready to be pasted into Excel?

The number of variables are far beyond what VF can show in the grid in the above screenshot (30-80 variables total).

Any thoughts?  **Thanks!**

Comment: Since you already have the JSON in the VF page, you could use that to build out the CSV: either you can manually parse and spit out an csv file, but you dont want the headache of parsing the data to CSV then you can use library like papaparse (http://papaparse.com/#unparse)..

Comment: Advice to me:  What should I do with this question?  The Devs (at that time in that org) figured out how to accomplish this.  I do not have enough "historical info" to answer it myself.  :-/